# React testing library- how to assert intermediate state between async function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, fetch, react-testing-library

When I am testing the component in browser, it works fine. Upon button click, the text changes to 'bye'. Few seconds later, it changes back to 'hi' when data fetching is done. But in Jest, it could not detect the 'bye' text at all.

The error i got is "TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /bye/i"

Test.jsx

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    export const Test = () => {
          const [isLeaving, setIsLeaving] = useState(false);
          const handler = async () => {
            setIsLeaving(true);
            const response = await fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/1/full');
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log({ data });
            setIsLeaving(false);
          };
          return (
            <div>
              <p>{!isLeaving ? 'hi' : 'bye'}</p>
              <button onClick={handler}>click me</button>
            </div>
          );
        };
```

Test.spec.jsx

```
import {render,screen,waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'; 
import { Test } from './Test';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
    
describe('Test component test', () => {
              global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
                Promise.resolve({
                  json: () =>
                    Promise.resolve({
                      data: {
                        id: 1,
                        attributes: {
                          titles: { en: 'Fullmetal Alchemist' },
                          synopsis: 'After losine.'
                        }
                      }
                    })
                })
              );
              it('should show "bye" text before showing "hi" text when data fetching is don', async () => {
                const user = userEvent.setup();
                render(<Test />);
                expect(screen.getByText(/hi/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
                await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /click me/i }));
                expect(screen.getByText(/bye/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
                await waitFor(() => {
                  expect(screen.getByText(/hi/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
                });
              });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a deferred promise for `res.json()` method. Resolve it after the user click the button.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Test = () => {
  const [isLeaving, setIsLeaving] = useState(false);
  const handler = async () => {
    setIsLeaving(true);
    const response = await fetch('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime/1/full');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log({ data });
    setIsLeaving(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{!isLeaving ? 'hi' : 'bye'}</p>
      <button onClick={handler}>click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react';

import { Test } from './';

describe('Test component test', () => {
  const result = {
    data: {
      id: 1,
      attributes: {
        titles: { en: 'Fullmetal Alchemist' },
        synopsis: 'After losine.',
      },
    },
  };
  let jsonResolve;
  (global as any).fetch = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      json: () =>
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          jsonResolve = resolve;
        }),
    })
  );
  it('should show "bye" text before showing "hi" text when data fetching is don', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    render(<Test />);
    expect(screen.getByText(/hi/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /click me/i }));
    expect(screen.getByText(/bye/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    jsonResolve(result);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText(/hi/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75861970/index.test.tsx (8.919 s)
  Test component test
    ✓ should show "bye" text before showing "hi" text when data fetching is don (139 ms)

  console.log
    { data: { data: { id: 1, attributes: [Object] } } }

      at stackoverflow/75861970/index.tsx:9:13

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.337 s
```

Comment: Thank you so much. No wonder I could not assert the intermediate state because the promise was resolved instantly!